# Doesn't seem to be possible to call contract.methodObject.divestLiquidity

Tags: taquito

for this contract on ghostnet, `KT1T42LtbG7skEACAkWxNJGqdcCn52Nhp3pH`, if I go to tzkt or better call dev, I can see the entrypoint `divestLiquidity` is listed there. but if I call `contract.parameterSchema.generateSchema()` , the entrypoint `divestLiquidity` will be under `use`.

```
approve : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
default : {__michelsonType: 'unit', schema: 'unit'}
getAllowance : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
getBalance : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
getReserves : {__michelsonType: 'contract', schema: {…}}
getTotalSupply : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
transfer : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
use :
  schema : divestLiquidity : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
    initializeExchange : {__michelsonType: 'nat', schema: 'nat'}
    investLiquidity : {__michelsonType: 'nat', schema: 'nat'}
    tezToTokenPayment : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
    tokenToTezPayment : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
    veto : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
    vote : {__michelsonType: 'pair', schema: {…}}
    withdrawProfit : {__michelsonType: 'address', schema: 'address'}
  __michelsonType : "or"
```

It also doesn't seem to be possible to call `contract.methodObject.divestLiquidity`.  Is it possible that I can use all entrypoints under `use`  directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both! I think I found what I'm looking for.
for `ExtractSignatures` and `getSignature` , it doesn't seem to provide a precise Michelson type in some cases. For example, `set (string)` only shows `set`. `contract 'param` shows `contract`. `option 'a`  shows `'a`.  is it possible to get precise types and annotations?

Comment: ExtractSignature and getSignature are designed to simplify Michelson type down to javascript abstraction.
genrateSchema() might be closest to what you’re looking for

Answer (score 0):

I poked around a little bit and can see that with:

```
const contract = await tezos.contract.at('KT1T42LtbG7skEACAkWxNJGqdcCn52Nhp3pH')
const entrypoints = contract.parameterSchema.ExtractSignatures();
const op = await contract.methods.divestLiquidity(1,2,3).send();
```

the `contract.methods.divestLiquidity` is there and usable I am just not sure about the validation within your contract for what it wants  and had it purposely fail with zero gasLimit so I wouldnt leave any lasting interactions with the contract.

The params are usable in both `methods` and `methodsObject` only difference are how they take params `methods.<entrypoint>(params, order, specific)` or `methodsObject.<entrypoint>({0: firstParam, 1: nextParam})` please let me know if this helps at all or if this is not even close to what you are experiencing!

From Zainen Suzuki in Slack.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what Zainen is saying above and would like to add.
I can see the contract hierarchy of %divestLiquidity is under %use.

I found `contract.parameterSchema.ExtractSignatures()` helpful when it comes to what entry points a contract has with taquito, a screenshot of the response below.

Then `contract.methodsObject.divestLiquidity().getSignature()` and `contract.methods.divestLiquidity().getSignature()` will show you how to pass param to make the contract calls.

[image]

From Hui-An Yang in Slack.